# Check username exists in database or not

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express

doing this username checking in c#,it always enter if same name given,It never shows checking,plz tell why?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ro;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name from [Machine]", con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
            query=rdr.GetString(0);
            if (query == textBox1.Text)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("MachineName Already exists!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                this.db.Datastore("INSERT INTO [Roamani].[dbo].[Machine] ([Name],[Type],[AETitle],[IPAddress],[Port]) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + comboBox1.SelectionBoxItem + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')");
                this.Hide();
                m.Show();
                return;
            }
            //return;
        }
```

Comment: _it always enter if same name given,It never shows checking_ What is that mean? o_O Did you debug your code for what is going on exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül:yes,it always enetr if same name given

Comment: You're checking against table login but inserting into table Machine? If you want to check for machine name, use table machine, not table login.

Comment: @okrumnow:sry,but am change the tablename now,then only not showing checking with database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question, you are selecting all users from database and comparing one by one with the new username be entered thus may cause performance issues.

You Can Try Like This:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your ConnectionString");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [login] where UserName=@Name",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtUsername.Text);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.HasRows)
{
   // "UserName Already Taken";
 }
else
{
  //"UserName Available";
}
```

Comment: Or a count(*) return one field instead of a row?

Comment: Yes, instead of select count( * ) we should use count for One Column mainly PK like count(PK). AS select count( * ) will be slower as it attempts to fetch everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool CheckAlredyExistProd(string catid)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblMyCart WHERE Product_Category='" + catid + "'");
        command.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader red = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (red.HasRows)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation as to how this solves OP's problem